# Using Op-Amp to form a uni-gain buffer, what happen if IN+ is floating?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If an amplifier is supplied with VCC and VSS and form as a buffer, what is the amplifier's output voltage once the positive input pin is disconnected(floating)?
[image]
Is there any method to calculate out the output voltage?

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the scenario you are describing and tell us what you are interested in getting out of this.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: This looks like homework so you need to show your work.

Comment: Knowing nothing about the amplifier it is impossible to tell. The problem is indeterminate.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. As @Transistor has answered well below, your input is indeterminate. If you're hoping for a definite answer from the sketchy question you have written, then you'll be disappointed - it's impossible. To discuss this more, you must first greatly expand your question, Add good and lengthy detail explaining what you are doing and why. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Thanks.

Comment: Understood, thanks very much for you guys' advice and comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. The setup.*

Since this is a voltage follower circuit, the output voltage will be whatever the input voltage is.

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa170.pdf?ts=1588059219234) says that it has

> Low Bias Current: 15 pA (Maximum)

and an input impedance of 100 MΩ. That means that it will be very susceptible to pickup of stray voltages and depending on how much of an "antenna" the input is connected to it will pick up everything from mains hum to radio wave signals. The output will follow whatever the input sees.